# Dynamically add/remove options from app drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawer

I have created an application and used navigation drawer that has been created automatically by the Android Studio app.

I am trying to figure out if I can add/remove options from drawer dynamically.
For that, I assume I would have to get reference to DrawerListView and its adapter. I would have to make changes on adapter, and then notify view that there was a change... in theory... I have no idea how to do this.

If you have any idea, let me know. Thanks.

Here is my poor attempt to do that:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MyActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

ListView mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, null, false);

android.widget.ListAdapter adapter = mDrawerListView.getAdapter();
```

I have to say that this implementation is quite different than any I have seen online.